# I want to do two functions that calls each other, but when I do that, one function gets error as not declared

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

In `input()`, where I call `Table()`, I get an error that the function is not declared:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void input(){
   Table();
}

void Table(){
   input();
}

int main(){
   input();
   Table();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Call function that is not defined yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229198/c-call-function-that-is-not-defined-yet)

Answer (score 5):

At the point where you're attempting to call Table(), the function is not known yet. Add a forward declaration to make it work, like so:

```
using namespace std;

void Table();  // <-- forward declaration

void input(){ Table(); }
void Table(){ input(); }

int main(){ input(); Table(); }
```